# Determine plot bounds of a given function to highlight interesting behavior?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, trigonometric-functions

Am working on plotting software. Am trying to find an algorithm that would automatically generate x and y bounds for the plot such that the interesting behavior is shown. There are some algorithms like Newton/Raphson method as well as the synthetic division algorithm for determining upper and lower bounds of a function, however these functions are only applicable if the function actually has x intercepts. My next thought is to differentiate the function along a set of x values [a,b] and if sign changes/zeroes occur, such as that of a vertex, then that is interesting behavior we will want to include and will form the basis of the bounds, however this leads to another problem of determining what range of x values to plug in.